# Trap gnome-terminal close button

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal, bash-history

I can trap the `exit` command from a `gnome-terminal` window using the 
Bash `trap` command, but it only works if the user types `exit` in the terminal window. If the user clicks the close button instead, the trap exit handler is not executed.

**Background information:**
I would like to save Bash history to a custom history file when the user clicks the close button. I have used `export HISTFILE=/tmp/custom.hist`, this works in many cases (when the user clicks the close button in the gnome-terminal, the history is saved to the given file), but in some cases the history is not saved, so I am looking for alternatives to setting the `HISTFILE` environment variable..

Comment: The exit trap does get executed for me when I close the tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to trap SIGHUP;

From `man 7 signal`:

```
SIGHUP        1       Term    Hangup detected on controlling terminal or death of controlling process
```

So to trap both SIGHUP and EXIT:

```bsh
trap 'export HISTFILE=/tmp/custom.hist' 1 EXIT
```

or:

```bsh
trap 'export HISTFILE=/tmp/custom.hist' SIGHUP EXIT
```

Answer (score 1):

You could save the history file after every command. This trick is usually used to synchronize the history for multiple windows, but would work in your case.  See for example, [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1288/preserve-bash-history-in-multiple-terminal-windows)